# Is there a Cordova/PhoneGap Plugin that uses Bluetooth Classic for iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, bluetooth, mfi

I'm trying to find a bluetooth classic (External accessory framework/MFi) plugin for Cordova. I have been unsuccessful. Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that have found this question - I had to build my own plugin to handle classic bluetooth with Cordova/Phone Gap, there were no off the shelf answers... Best of luck !

Added a link to my GIT Repo of the Plugin framework I setup:

https://github.com/NPSconsultingLLC/BluetoothClassicCordova

Comment: Hi Nathan, Were you able to integrate MFi profiles into the classic solution for iOS?  I haven't been able to find any information on MFi and Phonegap.  Could you possibly provide anything you've learned that may be helpful?

Comment: Hey Xceph - Yes we were able to build a MFi App using phoneGap, but we were piggybacking on our vendors MFi approval. I'm happy to provide you with any assistance I can, but much of this does predate my involvement with the program. Feel free to drop me a message Nathan.Stryker@gmail.com

Comment: @Nathan hey there, can I know how you did your plugin or if you have uploaded it to a repository so I can check it? We're developing a Cordova app which requires to connect to a Classic Bluetooth POS device, I'd love to check your plugin, maybe it could help me with this...

Comment: Yep Feel free to send me an email I'm happy to link you to my Repo- the plugin is a bit rough, but it should give you an idea for how to get started. Nathan.Stryker@gmail.com